# how to create hierarchically structured folder using for each loop php?

Tags: php

i have create hierarchically folder like folder under sub folder
if exist samename folder than skip create folder and enter those directory and create nextone folder
foldername taken from array

example

$folderarray = `array('0'=>'8','1'=>'8','6'=>'9');`

here array value 8 ,8 ,9 is folder name
and i have try to create
first folder name 8 than second create folder name 8
under folder 8 than create folder name 9 under folder name 8
structure like  8 under => 8 under => 9

how to do?

i have try using foreach like this but not create properly

```
foreach ($folderarray as $path){
   $source = "D:/xampp/htdocs/xyz/img/";
    $chkpath = $source.$path;

    if (!file_exists($chkpath)) {

        mkdir($chkpath, 0777, true);
        $source = $chkpath;


    }
    else{
        $source = $chkpath;
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: not create properly? maybe the parent folder has permission that blocks you from creating the folder?

Comment: folder created but not the proper way like folder under folder

Comment: So reading from the code, it seems like its creating folder /8 then inside folder /8, there is another folder /8 and then inside there is folder /9 right?

Comment: yes , i have create folder 8 than under create 8 than create 9 under 8

Comment: now create all folder under $source  path and this is bugg

Comment: Define $source outside of the loop, and append the current path segment to it inside of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to do:

```
$source = "D:/xampp/htdocs/xyz/img";
foreach ($folderarray as $path){
    $chkpath = $source . "/" . $path;

    if (!file_exists($chkpath)) {
        mkdir($chkpath, 0777, true);
        $source = $chkpath;
    } else {
        $source = $chkpath;
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have mistake creating path after create someone folder
you have forgot / in new path

try to like this

$folderarray = array('0'=>'8','1'=>'9','6'=>'1');

$source = "D:/xampp/htdocs/xyz/img/";

```
foreach ($folderarray as $path){

    $chkpath = $source.$path;
    if (!file_exists($chkpath)) {
        mkdir($chkpath, 0777, true);
        $source = $chkpath.'/';


    }
    else{
        $source = $chkpath.'/';

    }


}
```